# PostgreSQL query is limiting returned values in GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql, group-by

The below query is not including all the data available, specifically in the

```
line12 campaign.campaign_name AS "Campaign Name"
```

Each "Group Name" should have 4 - 6 "Campaign Name" returned with the request. What is happening is only 1 campaign per group is returning any data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (call.call_id) 
   call.call_id AS "Call ID",
   call.call_started AS "Call Date/Time", 
   call.disposition AS "Disposition", 
   call.repeat_call AS "Repeat Call", 
   call.duration AS "Duration",
   call.source AS "Caller ID", 
   call.tracking AS "Tracking Number", 
   call.ring_to AS "Ring to Number", 
   org_unit.org_unit_name AS "Group Name", 
   org_unit.org_unit_parent_id AS "Parent ID",
   campaign.campaign_name AS "Campaign Name",
SUM(CASE WHEN indicator.indicator_name = 'Acquired Name' AND indicator_score.score_value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) as "Acquired Name",
SUM(CASE WHEN indicator.indicator_name = 'Acquired Email' AND indicator_score.score_value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) as "Acquired Email",
SUM(CASE WHEN indicator.indicator_name = 'Acquired Phone Number' AND indicator_score.score_value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) as "Acquired Phone Number",
SUM(CASE WHEN indicator.indicator_name = 'Lead Score (c)' AND indicator_score.score_value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Lead Score (c)",
SUM(CASE WHEN indicator.indicator_name = 'Promotion Mention' AND indicator_score.score_value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) as "Promotion Mention",
SUM(CASE WHEN indicator.indicator_name = 'Sales Inquiry' AND indicator_score.score_value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) as "Sales Inquiry",
SUM(CASE WHEN indicator.indicator_name = 'Voice Message' AND indicator_score.score_value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) as "Voice Message"
FROM call
JOIN indicator_score ON indicator_score.call_id = call.call_id
JOIN indicator ON indicator.indicator_id = indicator_score.indicator_id
JOIN org_unit ON org_unit.org_unit_id = call.org_unit_id
JOIN campaign ON campaign.campaign_ou_id = call.org_unit_id
WHERE org_unit.billing_id = 4097
AND DATE(call.call_started) BETWEEN '2017-03-01' and '2017-03-07' 
group by call.call_id, org_unit.org_unit_name, org_unit.org_unit_parent_id,
campaign.campaign_name
ORDER BY call.call_id
```

Here is a spreadsheet of the data that is returned and a sample of what the data should actually look like. [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JbYgPKqqUfp1tTEFk4nwnUg-W0AHDzDtye6sMeBG0oU/edit?usp=sharing)

I hope I am explaining this correctly, but the problem is only one campaign per group is populating and I need all available campaigns to populate.

I tried removing the "group by campaign.campaign_name" and kept getting this error:

> /* ERROR:  column "campaign.campaign_name" must appear in the GROUP BY
>   clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 12:
>   campaign.campaign_name      AS "Campaign Name",
>                   ^ */

The whole query could be garbage, it was pieced together by three amateurs so that could be it also...

Comment: The `DISTINCT ON (call.call_id) ` bit at the top means the query will only return the first record for each call_id. Is that the intention? Otherwise query looks okay. Why do you think the "group by" is at fault?

Comment: Yes, the call_id is the distinct value that is needed. When I remove the distinct I get rows with duplicate call_id's and every column is duplicated except the campaign name. That lead me to believe that the group by campaign, was causing the problem.

Comment: Can an org_unit have more than one campaign?

Comment: Yes, the org_unit can have more than one campaign. Typically it will have 4-6 campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

Might help to understand your relations better if you post the results of this query:

```
SELECT c.call_id,
    string_agg(cm.campaign_name,' | ') as campaigns,
    string_agg(i.indicator_name,' | ') as indicators
FROM call c
JOIN indicator_score is ON is.call_id = c.call_id
JOIN indicator i ON i.indicator_id = is.indicator_id
JOIN org_unit o ON o.org_unit_id = c.org_unit_id
JOIN campaign cm ON cm.campaign_ou_id = c.org_unit_id
WHERE o.billing_id = 4097
    AND DATE(c.call_started) BETWEEN '2017-03-01' and '2017-03-07'
group by c.call_id order by c.call_id limit 10
```

Just guessing, but this version might work for you:

```
SELECT call.call_id AS "Call ID",
    call.call_started AS "Call Date/Time",
    call.disposition AS "Disposition",
    call.repeat_call AS "Repeat Call",
    call.duration AS "Duration",
    call.source AS "Caller ID",
    call.tracking AS "Tracking Number",
    call.ring_to AS "Ring to Number",
    org_unit.org_unit_name AS "Group Name",
    org_unit.org_unit_parent_id AS "Parent ID",
    string_agg(campaign.campaign_name,' | ') as "Campaign Names",
    SUM(CASE WHEN indicator.indicator_name = 'Acquired Name' AND indicator_score.score_value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) as "Acquired Name",
    SUM(CASE WHEN indicator.indicator_name = 'Acquired Email' AND indicator_score.score_value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) as "Acquired Email",
    SUM(CASE WHEN indicator.indicator_name = 'Acquired Phone Number' AND indicator_score.score_value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) as "Acquired Phone Number",
    SUM(CASE WHEN indicator.indicator_name = 'Lead Score (c)' AND indicator_score.score_value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Lead Score (c)",
    SUM(CASE WHEN indicator.indicator_name = 'Promotion Mention' AND indicator_score.score_value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) as "Promotion Mention",
    SUM(CASE WHEN indicator.indicator_name = 'Sales Inquiry' AND indicator_score.score_value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) as "Sales Inquiry",
    SUM(CASE WHEN indicator.indicator_name = 'Voice Message' AND indicator_score.score_value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) as "Voice Message"
FROM call
JOIN indicator_score ON indicator_score.call_id = call.call_id
JOIN indicator ON indicator.indicator_id = indicator_score.indicator_id
JOIN org_unit ON org_unit.org_unit_id = call.org_unit_id
JOIN campaign ON campaign.campaign_ou_id = call.org_unit_id
WHERE org_unit.billing_id = 4097
AND DATE(call.call_started) BETWEEN '2017-03-01' and '2017-03-07'
GROUP BY call.call_id, call.call_started, call.disposition, call.repeat_call, 
    call.duration, call.source, call.tracking, call.ring_to, 
    org_unit.org_unit_name, org_unit.org_unit_parent_id
ORDER BY call.call_id
```

Comment: Thank you for trying. The problem here is that the campaign_name is now duplicated on one row instead of my version where the campaign was duplicated on multiple rows. Either way, I should not have any call_id duplicated anywhere but especially on campaigns

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. But how can you pick a winner? Using `distinct on` is going to grab the first one it finds. Is that good enough? You said, "problem is only one campaign per group is populating and I need all available campaigns to populate", so if you have one row per call_id, how can all campaigns be represented?

Comment: Also, in your spreadsheet it looks like there are rows missing compared to expected results. Does my version of the query show additional rows or does it match the original results?

Comment: The relationship should be one call_id to one campaign, but there should be multiple campaigns per group (each campaign only having one call_id).  I think I am going to have to break this into 2 or 3 queries then use excel to bring it back together.